# Dynamic React Text Inputs

Tags: reactjs, dynamic

I am relatively new to React so sorry if this is a really easy/stupid question.

So I am making an app where you provide a number of months and depending on the number of months that number of text fields need to show up. Ex. 5 months = 5 new text fields. How would I go about doing that? I have tried various methods to no avail hence why I am asking here. Thank you for your help.

```
class MonthlyInputs extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let monthInputs = [1, 2, 3];
    let items = [];

    function updateInputs(event) {
      monthInputs = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < event.target.value; i++) {
        monthInputs.push(i);
      }
      console.log(monthInputs)
      for (let i = 0; i < monthInputs.length; i++) {
        items.push(<li key={i}>list item {i}</li>);
      }
    }

    for (const [index, value] of monthInputs.entries()) {
      items.push(<li key={index}>{value}</li>)
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={updateInputs} />
        {items}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to visualise what you're trying to achieve, without seeing what you're trying.

Can you throw down some code, even though it doesn't work? :) Will help us.

Comment: What methods have you tried and why didn't they work? Saving the # of months to component state, and then mapping an array with size of the months # into text fields would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted what you're trying to implement.

Let me know if you have any questions.

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-liskov-iicor?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

Consider saving your variables in state. Also you shouldn't declare funcions in render funcion. Here is code:

```
class App extends Component{

constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
   monthInputs: [],
  }
}

   updateInputs = (event) => {
    let  monthInputs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < event.target.value; i++) {
      monthInputs.push(i);
    }

    this.setState({
      monthInputs
    })
  }

  render(){
    const {monthInputs} = this.state;

    return(
      <div>
      <input  type="number" value={monthInputs} onChange={this.updateInputs} />
      {monthInputs.length > 0 && monthInputs.map((number, index)=> 
      <li key={number}>{number}</li> )}
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[And here is link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-architecture-9xlwv)